# UserApp user search doesn't return any results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, userapp

I'm querying UserApp for users and I feel like I've tried everything. Here's my code:

```
UserApp.User.search({
                "page": 1,
                "page_size": 100,
                "fields": "*",
                "filters": {
                    "query": "email:example@email.com"
                }
            }, function(error, result){
                console.log(error);
                console.log(result);
            });
```

This isn't returning any error, and in the results object, it just responds with an empty array. The email is correct, and I've tried with and without sorting, fields as "*" and "mixed", query as "email:example@email.com", "name:Stephen", "Stephen", and "*". The app_id is set properly, and I get use UserApp.User.get() to get myself when I'm logged in, but the above code never works. Error keeps coming back null and result is:

```
Object {items: Array[0], next_page: null, total_pages: 0, total_items: 0}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Those "" above should be "(star)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UserApp.initialize({appId: "APP_ID", token: "TOKEN_CREATED_IN_TOKENS_SETTINGS"});
UserApp.User.search({
    "page": 1,
    "page_size": 250,
    "fields": "*"
}, function(error, result){
    console.log(result.items);
});
```